# Are there any good options for baking out a Django site as static files?

Tags: python, database, django, amazon-s3

Say you have an existing database-backed Django site. Something simple, like single model containing a record for every minor league baseball team. The model is accessed by one view that lists all the teams, and another that accepts a slug and then creates a detail page all about that team.

Is there a good option for converting the app into a stack of baked out flat files, so that it could be served from a static file service like Amazon's S3?

I've toyed with [Hyde](http://ringce.com/hyde) but it's not clear to me how it applies to an existing site backed by a database.

Any advice would be very much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[django-medusa](https://github.com/mtigas/django-medusa) is largely unmaintained. These are some alternatives mentioned in the project's README:

> - [django-bakery](https://github.com/datadesk/django-bakery), built and maintained  the lovely people at the [Los Angeles Times Data Desk](http://datadesk.latimes.com/).   (Read about it
>     [here](http://datadesk.latimes.com/posts/2012/03/introducing-django-bakery/).)
> - [The alsoicode/django-medusa fork](https://github.com/alsoicode/django-medusa), by [Brandon
>     Taylor](https://github.com/alsoicode). Among other things, it's been
>     kept up to date for newer versions of Django.
> - [django-freeze](https://github.com/fabiocaccamo/django-freeze) by [Fabio Caccamo](https://github.com/fabiocaccamo).
> - [django-staticgen](https://github.com/mishbahr/django-staticgen) by [Mishbah Razzaque](https://github.com/mishbahr).

Answer (score 2):

I understand your intent, but any decent framework these days offers some sort of [caching mecanism](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/?from=olddocs) that alleviate the pains of dynamic content. With a properly implemented cache, the difference between static and dynamic will be trivial. Trust me.

Happy coding, friend.

Comment: Thanks. I totally agree that caching is the Onefold Path of Enlightenment when it comes to deploying database-driven applications. In my use current case, tho, I'm actually thinking more about cost than load. It's just cheaper to serve flat files, and I'd like to try and leverage that.

Answer (score 2):

A new one has just been announced, though it has existed and been used by its author for quite some time:

[django-medusa](http://v3.mike.tig.as/blog/2012/06/30/django-medusa-rendering-django-sites-static-html/).

I haven't tried using it yet, but it sure looks good: I will be!

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar setup using Django but on GAE. I have created a build script which I use to build my static HTML files. Since GAE's version of Django templates is slightly different, this might need some testing.

But essentially you do something like

```
from django.template import Template, Context
from django.template.loader import get_template

t = get_template('template1.html')   #Need to verify this. GAE template allows me to just call template.render(path, context). Not sure about pure Django templates
c = Context({ 'variable' : 'value'})
with open("file1.html", "w") as f:
    f.write(t.render(c))   #This works for me, but if this doesn't in pure Django, try render_to_string
```

HTH

Comment: Thanks for the tip. And how do you deploy? Do you write a bit of code that loops through the database and run the code above against every entry -- and then push the result?

Comment: Yes my build script essentially grabs content from some files, merges them into the templates and creates the static HTML. I haven't set it up to automatically push since I don't change the content there very often, but that should be fairly easy to do.

Comment: Okay, that sort of "custom" build script is kind of where I've always figured I'd have to end up, but it's great to here the POV of others. And there's always part of me that thinks that if I just ask the Internet, some wicked Python master might have an automagic solution waiting.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking for a dynamic site to host in a static environment, that is impossible. The only way is to export all the files, put them into a static server. You can do it with `wget`, it will copy all the files and convert them to html.

One fallback of this problem is, it can only create html files, if there are links to the pages, ie. search forms etc. *will not* work, Javascript based linking *may not* work.

Comment: Thanks. I totally hear you on the dynamic v. static issue. In my fantasy delusion, there's some slick Python package that will loop through your database and bake out the pages one by one, like wget from the inside out. Though I'm probably kidding myself and just have to bite the bullet and grind it wget style.

Comment: In static environments, you cannot *run* any application. But so long as you do not update quite regularly, `wget` will handle things well, and if you update, you need to wget to you dynamic server (which is local, i guess) then update the files.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with anything that will convert an existing django site to a static html site.  It might be worth looking at the suite of new django/python PaaS providers.  A site like this should be easy to get running on one of these platforms and it should be pretty cheap month to month.

Some providers you might want to checkout include:

- [Gondor.io](http://gondor.io)
- [ep.io](http://ep.io)
- [Django Zoom](http://djangozoom.com/)

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I'm actually considering static files as an alternative to PaaS sites. I primarily use Google App Engine, but I'm looking to cut costs ahead of their upcoming switch to a much more expensive pricing schedule.